# Kaggle kernel, unable to create file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas, kaggle

[image]

I'm getting this error and have tried from last 2 hours but unable to figure out ,what can be the possible solution. Even it looks a silly one but I'm unable to solve it.

Comment: Is this on your local machine?

Comment: No, using kaggle kernal

Comment: Why remove the accept? Is there an issue with my answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can't write to a file in a directory above your workspace in the kaggle kernel.

```
# works
open("foo.csv", "w").write("contents")

# OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system
open("../foo.csv", "w").write("contents")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is directory to take an input files onto the kaggle kernel not to provide output.

Answer (score 0):

You are in `'input'` directory which you have no access to create files. The solution is creating your file in `'working'` directory. So, the path would be:

```
'/kaggle/working/your_file.csv'
```